# Are tags used as meta keywords and how are they stored in the database?

Tags: support, tags

Does Stack Overflow use tags on questions as keywords for SEO purposes and how are tags stored in the database?

[image: Screenshot of the tag section]

Comment: Tags are for connecting experts to questions, nothing less, nothing more. They **are not** SEO keywords - I hope you do not treat them as such. They are stored in [the database](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) as a `nvarchar (250)` type field.

Comment: Note that on [so] the most popular tag (by questions) that isn't in the question's title is added to the `<title>` of the page. So, for example, the question [SQL Count each occurence of words separated by comma](//stackoverflow.com/q/72186891/) has "sql server - SQL Count each occurence of words separated by comma - Stack Overflow" as it's `<title>`, as [[tag:sql-server]] is the most popular tag that isn't already in the title ([[tag:sql]] is the most popular, but is already in the title).

Comment: The tag as SEO was actually [answered on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190)... I wonder why this was migrated? But in short no one knows exactly how SEO is optimized (the search engine companies don't disclose the specifics) so what we do have are guidelines regarding use of tags and that's it's not necessary to include tags in the titles.

Comment: I really fail to see "what are tags" have to do with how they are stored in a database.

Comment: @bad_coder it was migrated from SO to meta.SO. Not from meta.SO to MSE.

Comment: @Braiam ain't what tags are encompasses how they are stored? In any case, that was the only way I found that would make the question a useful addition.

Answer (score 5):

**What tags are and how do they work**

Tags exist to connect experts to questions and not for SEO (they are [used](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417965/are-tags-used-as-meta-keywords-and-how-are-they-stored-in-the-database#comment909079_417965) *to an extent* for the latter, though). This includes:

- Expedited duplicate closure. Users with gold tag badge in the respective tag can *single-handedly* (with some restrictions) close questions as duplicates, as well as edit in multiple duplicate targets into the list displayed on already closed posts.
- Following and ignoring. Users can add tags to respective lists to ensure questions from the tags they are interested in are shown, and those they aren't — hidden.
- Review filtering. Many review queues can be filtered by tags to allow reviewers to focus on posts where they have subject matter expertise.
- Searching. Search query can contain any number (up to the query length limit, of course) of tags via `[tagname]` syntax, narrowing the subsequent search results.
- Usage guidance. Every tag has (if it is written, that is) an *excerpt* and a *wiki*, describing what the tag is about, how and when to use it, and in many cases examples, resources, and even lists of prominent Q&A pairs.

**How are they stored in the database**

Information about tags is stored in 3 tables: the `Posts` table (in the `Tags` field, which is an `nvarchar(250)` field formatted as a list of tag names enclosed in `<>`), the `PostTags` table (the relationship between tags and posts), and the `Tags` table (the information about each tag).

Stack Exchange [database schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) is publicly available if you need more info. There is also an open source [explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) (SEDE) where you can make queries against the database.

Comment: @rene yeah, forgot to specify those (was too focused on the OP's context)! I'll take your word for them being derived from the `Tags` and `PostTags` - from the schema, I surmised the `Posts.Tags` field was not connected to those tables and updated separately, though?

Comment: @rene ah, sorry, I think I know the problem - it wasn't my intention to specify the `Posts.Tags` the column as the source of truth with others being derived from it, but I can see how my wording is messy in that regards. I'll try to clarify